# Customs for closing eyes for Keriyat Shema

Tags: minhag, shema

When davening by Rabbi Chaim Pinchas Scheinberg one Friday night he did not cover his eyes for Shema.

Are there any sources that suggest merely closing one's eyes for Shema rather than covering them with one's hands?

Comment: related - glasses and shema http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13585/glasses-and-shema

Comment: See Aruch Hashulchan seif 3